# PGPool Failover

Tags: postgresql, pgpool

We have a high available database architecture that contains PGPool cluster with 3 instances, and at the backend PostgreSQL database cluster with 2 instances.

Our PostgreSQL and PGPool versions are, respectively, PostgreSQL 10.17 and pgpool-II version 4.1.9(karasukiboshi).

We tested our PGPool cluster for failover. Our steps were:

- Stopping PGPool service on the master node. -> Successful.
- Killing PGPool service on the master node. -> Successful.
- Rebooting PGPool master node server. -> Unsuccessful.

I found failover related topics that are related my first 2 cases, but there is no topic rebooting PGPool master node server.

Does any of you had similar problem? This is not capability of PGPool? We don' t what the problem is.

PS: If you need I will update the topic with my configuration files.

The log entries when we reboot the master PGPool server:

```
pid 669752: LOG: authentication timeout May 10 17:22:51 my_server_name pgpool[3536624]: 2022-05-10 17:22:51: pid 670080:
LOG: authentication timeout May 10 17:22:51 my_server_name pgpool[3536624]: 2022-05-10 17:22:51: pid 670090:
LOG: authentication timeout May 10 17:22:51 my_server_name pgpool[3536624]: 2022-05-10 17:22:51: pid 669677:
LOG: authentication timeout May 10 17:22:51 my_server_name pgpool[3536624]: 2022-05-10 17:22:51: pid 670092: 
LOG: authentication timeout May 10 17:22:51 my_server_name pgpool[3536624]: 2022-05-10 17:22:51: pid 670094: LOG: authenticatio
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have watchdog configured? Two additional pgpool nodes should be able to elect new master node. What about up/down ip script - is it executed? What do you have in two available nodes logs after master reboot?

Comment: I took over this project in the middle. Even though I was told the system configured for high availability, it is not. There were fundemental problems such as failover_scripts and ssh configurations. After that, it was fine.